# How to show the success message of PHP in html page on Form submission

Tags: php, html

I am developing website in html. In Careers.html page i am having Apply button. On clicking that apply button it will send the mail using php file. On suceess event i need to set the alert or to show the div on the same Careers.html page.

Careers.html

```
<form method="post" action="Applyresume.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
     <tr>
     <td>First Name  </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="First_Name" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Last Name </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="Last_Name" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>E-mail  </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="email" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Phone  </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="Phone_No" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Attachment  </td>
    <td><input type="file" name="attachment" maxlength="50" allow="text/*" class="applytext" required></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" class="send-resume" value="SEND" style="margin-left:24%;">
    <input type="reset" value="RESET" style="margin-left:8%"></td>
     </tr>
     </form>
```

Applyresume.php

```
 <?php 
    if($_POST && isset($_FILES['attachment']))
    {  
        $name= $_POST['First_Name'];
        $lname= $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $phonenum = $_POST['Phone_No'];
        $from_email = $_POST['email']; //sender email
        $recipient_email = 'nisha@acute.company'; //recipient email
        $subject = 'Test Email '; //subject of email
        $message = 'Resume attached below.'; //message body
            $emailbod = "$name
        $lname
         $email
         $phonenum";
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['attachment']['error'];

        $user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        if($file_error>0)
        {
            die('upload error');
        }
        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));


            $boundary = md5("sanwebe"); 
            //header
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

            //plain text 
            $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
            $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($emailbod)); 

            //attachment
            $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
            $body .= $encoded_content; 



        $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject,  $body, $headers);
        if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
        { 
                 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Thanks for your interest. Your Resume has been sent to HR@prominData.com");window.location.assign("Careers.html");</script>';
        }else
       {
             echo"<script>alert('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.')</script>";
        }

    }
    ?>
```

My problem is I need to set the success alert in the same html page.
But here my success alert is opening in PHP page.

How to add this php code in same html page?

Comment: If you want the message on the same page then you have to put the php code on the same page.

Comment: if i put the php code on same it is not working.

Comment: check my answer @Nisha

Comment: Yeah because your file's extension is `.html` not `.php` You have to do it through AJAX then...

Comment: @Lal Thank you.. Your code has worked for me

Comment: Great..Glad that it helped.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the message or alert on the same page, you can just copy your `php` code in the same HTML page. Do it as below

**your_html.php**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
     <tr>
     <td>First Name  </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="First_Name" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Last Name </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="Last_Name" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>E-mail  </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="email" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Phone  </td>
     <td><input type="TextBox" name="Phone_No" class="applytext" required></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Attachment  </td>
    <td><input type="file" name="attachment" maxlength="50" allow="text/*" class="applytext" required></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" class="send-resume" value="SEND" style="margin-left:24%;">
    <input type="reset" value="RESET" style="margin-left:8%"></td>
     </tr>
     </form>


<?php 
    if($_POST && isset($_FILES['attachment']))
    {  
        $name= $_POST['First_Name'];
        $lname= $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $phonenum = $_POST['Phone_No'];
        $from_email = $_POST['email']; //sender email
        $recipient_email = 'nisha@acute.company'; //recipient email
        $subject = 'Test Email '; //subject of email
        $message = 'Resume attached below.'; //message body
            $emailbod = "$name
        $lname
         $email
         $phonenum";
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['attachment']['error'];

        $user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        if($file_error>0)
        {
            die('upload error');
        }
        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));


            $boundary = md5("sanwebe"); 
            //header
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

            //plain text 
            $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
            $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($emailbod)); 

            //attachment
            $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
            $body .= $encoded_content; 



        $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject,  $body, $headers);
        if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
        { 
                 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Thanks for your interest. Your Resume has been sent to HR@prominData.com");window.location.assign("Careers.html");</script>';
        }else
       {
             echo"<script>alert('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.')</script>";
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Dont forget to remove the `action` attribute of `<form>`. Also the extension of your HTML page should be changed to `php`.

Answer (score 0):

set a condition on success
create a session 
$_SESSION['action] = "Your Massage";

and when page refresh.

there would be a place where you want to echo that massage.